# Openwrt:What can I do to package bin files into ipk packages？

Tags: openwrt

I've compiled the openwrt source and run it on my device (HC5661).Then I wrote a helloword.cpp (an example, any other name) using Eclipse IDE,helloword.bin was successfully generated by compilation and debugged on the target device using sftp and gdb.Now I want to compile helloword into an ipk package. What can I do to package bin files into ipk packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `SDK`. You can follow this steps:

1) Download the `OpenWrt-SDK`

2) In the `OpenWrt-SDK` folder run `./scripts/feeds/update -a && ./scripts/feeds/install -a`

3) Create a folder called `helloworld` in the path `OpenWrt-SDK/feeds/packages/utils/`

4) Inside this folder create a file called `Makefile` and new folder called `src`.

5) Inside the `src` folder put your `helloworld.cpp` and the `Makefile` which allows to compile it.

6) Your `Makefile` in the folder `OpenWrt-SDK/scripts/feeds/packages/utils/` should look like the following:

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

# Name and release number of this package
PKG_NAME:=helloworld
PKG_VERSION:=1.0
PKG_RELEASE:=0

# This specifies the directory where we're going to build the program.
# The root build directory, $(BUILD_DIR), is by default the build_mipsel
# directory in your OpenWrt SDK directory
PKG_BUILD_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME)

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/uclibc++.mk
include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk


# Specify package information for this program.
# The variables defined here should be self explanatory.

define Package/helloworld
SECTION:=utils
CATEGORY:=Utilities
TITLE:=helloworld exampke
endef

define Build/Prepare
    mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    $(CP) ./src/* $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/
endef


TARGET_CFLAGS += \
    -I$(STAGING_DIR)/usr/include \
    -D_GNU_SOURCE \
    -ggdb3

MAKE_FLAGS += \
    CFLAGS="$(TARGET_CFLAGS)" \
    LDFLAGS="$(TARGET_LDFLAGS)"

define Build/Compile
    $(call Build/Compile/Default, \
        CCOPTS="$(TARGET_CFLAGS)" \
        INCLUDE="$(EXTRA_CFLAGS)" \
        LDFLAGS="$(EXTRA_LDFLAGS)" \
    )
endef


define Package/helloworld/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/bin
    $(CP) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME) $(1)/bin/
endef


# This line executes the necessary commands to compile our program.
# The above define directives specify all the information needed, but this
# line calls BuildPackage which in turn actually uses this information to
# build a package.
$(eval $(call BuildPackage,helloworld))
```

7) In the `OpenWrt-SDK` folder run `./scripts/feeds update -i && ./scripts/feeds install helloworld`

8) In the same folder run `make package/helloworld/compile`

9) You can find your `.ipk` package in `OpenWrt-SDK/bin/ar71xx/packages/packages/`

PS: You may have to install `ccache` by typing (Ubuntu) `sudo apt-get install ccache`. You must not type your makefiles using spaces, you must use tabulator.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.I did it step by step as you said.But there was a mistake in step 8).

Comment: What about the step 7? What response did you receive? Did it say something like `Installing package 'helloworld'`?. If you run `make menuconfig` you should see your package in the list of available packages within the item `Utilities`

Comment: Yes,after step 7,I run 'make menuconfig' and see 'helloword' within the item 'Utilities',but step 8 is error as above.Now,I've got it lucky.The reason for the mistake is that step 5(src/makefile,I made a mistake).
Thank you very much for your help.I'll sort out the code and reply to it in later reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have hello.bin,You can put it into hello/src and:

## makefile(hello/):

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

PKG_NAME:=hello
PKG_VERSION:=1.0

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

define Package/hello
  CATEGORY:=Examples
  TITLE:=hello
  DEPENDS:=+libstdcpp
endef

define Package/hello/description
  hello world
endef

define Package/hello/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/usr/bin
    $(INSTALL_BIN) ./src/hello $(1)/usr/bin

endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,hello))
```

## makefile(hello/src):

```
all:hello
```

If not,You should put hello.cpp into hello/src and:

## makefile(hello/):

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

PKG_NAME:=hello
PKG_VERSION:=1.0

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

define Package/hello
  CATEGORY:=Examples
  TITLE:=hello
  DEPENDS:=+libstdcpp
endef

define Package/hello/description
  hello world
endef

define Package/hello/install
    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/usr/bin
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/hello $(1)/usr/bin

endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,hello))
```

## makefile(hello/src):

```
target=hello
all:$(target)

objects=hello.o
hello:$(objects)
    $(CXX) -o $(target) $(objects)

clean:
    @rm -rf $(objects)
```